# End point of Random Forest Tree

Tags: random-forest

I have a small doubt regarding the construction of a tree in Random Forest.
    My understanding of tree construction is this:

```
Suppose
-----------
N (total records of data set) =1000
M (total features) =30
n (Subset) = 500
m (fixed features to be used in RF) = 3

First Tree
-----------
1) Random sample data S1 (n) 
2) Take m features from M  eg: m2, m16, m29
3) Identify the best attribute – eg: m16 --> root node
4) Split S1 on m16 – gives 2 new subsets eg: S1_a and S1_b

5) For S1_a, select m eg: m1,m5,m10
6) Identify the best attribute – eg: m1
7) Split S1_a into S1_a1, S1_a2

8) For S1_b, select m eg: m11,m15,m10
9) Identify the best attribute – eg: m15
10) Split S1_b into S1_b1, S1_b2


Question is : When does this splitting get over ? 
i.e.After step 7, does S1_a1, and S1_a2 further split ? When does it end ?

Regards

Sri
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a general answer, but should be applicable to any random forest code implementation.  Random forests has a parameter called the node size.  The node size is the number of observations in a leaf of a tree at which point the algorithm will no longer keep splitting.  So in your example, if a split of a node with 4 observations resulted in 2 nodes each with 2 observations, and the node size were 2, then the algorithm would stop.

Of course, the smallest node size which makes physical sense is 1, so any value less than this should be rejected.

Based on reading the above paragraph you may be tempted to conclude that a small node size, e.g. 1, will lead to the best model.  In practice, this is not always the case.  At some point, continuing to split may no longer improve the predictive powers of the model.  So the best node size is the largest value which yields a reliable model.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Now it makes sense. Because most of the tutorials talk of building the tree, but none spoke about when to end it.. and while I was trying to draw the tree building process, it just seemed to go on and on. About the split size (node size), is there any default value ?

Comment: It depends on the implememtation you are using.  For R's `randomForest` package I believe the default node size for regression mode is 5.